# DB2 VARCHAR_FORMAT works with a Timestamp but not a Date

Tags: date, db2

I want to convert a Date column to a formatted string in DB2.  This SQL works fine:

```
select varchar_format(current timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

but this SQL gives an error:

```
select varchar_format(current date, 'YYYY-MM')
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

The error is:
[SQL0171] Argument 1 of function VARCHAR_FORMAT not valid.

In the first SQL, the first arg for VARCHAR_FORMAT is a timestamp, and that works.  In the second SQL, the first arg for VARCHAR_FORMAT is a date, and that doesn't work.

The IBM doc implies that there's only this one function, VARCHAR_FORMAT (and its synonym, TO_CHAR).

How am I supposed to convert a DATE (not a TIMESTAMP) to a string?  Or, do I have to convert the DATE to a TIMESTAMP first, then use VARCHAR_FORMAT?

I am running DB2 7.1 for i Series.

Update: converting to TIMESTAMP_ISO works.  But it's ugly:

```
select varchar_format(timestamp_iso(current date), 'YYYY-MM')
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

That one works.

Comment: I know it **should** work; that's why I'm asking the question.

I have discovered that converting to "ISO TIMESTAMP" works:
select varchar_format(timestamp_iso(current date), 'YYYY-MM')
from sysibm.sysdummy1;

but it seems like an ugly and too-verbose way of doing it.  And merely converting to TIMESTAMP gives a similar error as my original.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment, can't figure out the mini-Markdown formatting...

Comment: fwiw I just tried it on DB2 9.7 LUW and it works without any conversion

Comment: Does anybody know if implicit cust `date` as `timestamp` depends on some session parameters or just on DB version only?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `VARCHAR_FORMAT` function in DB2 for i only mentions TIMESTAMP values, not DATE. Some DB2 platforms will implicitly cast a DATE value to a TIMESTAMP when the statement is calling a TIMESTAMP-only function or when comparing the DATE to a TIMESTAMP, but not all do.